# How to create outline view for editor in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, outline-view

I have an custom editor created in eclipse, the outline view for this shows outline not available. I tried searching about this and I found the following links:

[FAQ How do I create an Outline view for my own language editor?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Outline_view_for_my_own_language_editor?)

[Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Programmer's Guide > Editors - Content outliners](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_workbench_outliner.htm)

[How to create an Outline View?](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t101941.html)

But none of them seemed to work for me. I May be doing it completely wrong; how do I create an outline view for the editor I created?

Comment: Those links are correct, so you need to show us your code so we can diagnose the issue.

Comment: greg-499: The problem is I am not able to understand where exactly tell the editor to set this as outline. Like in 3rd link it says:
layout.addView(IPageLayout.ID_OUTLINE, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.3f, layout.getEditorArea()); where do I use this??

Comment: That line is only needed if you are defining your own perspective. Stick to the `getAdapter` in the editor and the `ContentOutlinePage`

Comment: ok then. I will give it a try!